# Webstorm - errors after pub:build

Tags: dart, dart-html

I wrote simple example code in the WebStorm EAP

```
void main() {
  var main = new Element.html('<div class="main"></div>');
  document.body.children.add(main);
}
```

in Dartium - all is well, after pub:debug - - all is well,
but after pub:build project, in realise/index.html I do not see anything, only an error in the console:
    "main.dart.js:1159 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'at' of null"

Please explain to me what is the problem, and how can I get the correct build files.

Comment: How does `index.html` look like? Where is the file that contains above code? The code works fine here https://dartpad.dartlang.org/477d15b4e3934b69f58a399f152a7465

Comment: yes, I started code inthe dartpad - all is well,
but run in webStorm
http://prntscr.com/bg8tae
and
http://prntscr.com/bg8umt

Comment: I create a angular2 project, put this code, and after pab:release .html displayed correctly in the browser without errors. It's very strange.